# product pages under one category are blank

Tags: magento-1.7

On our web site we have thousands of products.but the problem is product page under some category are blank.I am unable to see any error. I try all the method to see error but failed.

Please help me to see the error message on product detail page.
Here is the [page](http://www.beautifulthingslighting.com/ceiling-lights.html).html click on any product under this category you will see the blank page.Now go to [this page](http://www.beautifulthingslighting.com/wall-lights.html) here click on any product it will work fine.

Comment: check number of products of particular category which shows no product in frontend from admin manage category section.

Comment: increase max_input_vars in php.ini or htaccess and check it.

Comment: do u check the error log ?

Comment: Yes in system log I am only getting this 2013-08-07T11:00:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home/bthings/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php on line 135

Comment: it is strange product under all the category is working fine except only ceillinh-lights and its subcategory.

Comment: hmm...is ceiling-lights default category? is it shows all the product in cateory product tab in admin.You can do one thing,Truncate the core_url_rewrite table.Delete all files from var/locks and Reindex. Take a backup of database before doing.

Comment: do u update ur maganto? or do u change store id or website id after creating first category?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670081/upgrading-magento-1-6-1-to-1-7-0-save-custom-module link as well

Comment: do u fix ur problem?

Comment: not yet unable to find error.

Answer (score 2):

To display errors go to your index.php and make sure both `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` are active. As this is a live webshop I suggest wrapping it in an `IF` statement that checks for your IP or something along that line. This will output errors directly to your screen.

I did a quick Google Search and found [this thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/286198/) and [this post](http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=69) that are about the specific error you mentioned showing up in your error log.

Comment: i did that but unable to see any error on my screen.

Comment: very strange, it might be something in your server configuration that is preventing you from outputting the errors. Did the 2 links help you in any way resolving the issue?

Comment: no I have updated the code as asked in the given thread.When i move the product of ceilling category to any other category it works fine.

Comment: You might need to debug by printing out what object it's trying to call there when the variable is no object. This way you can backtrace where the issue origionates